# node.js: Export variable contained in nested anonymous async functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

How do I export a variable (like 'data' below), so I can use the function below as a module:

```
//fooreader.js
var fs = require("fs");
var fileName = "foo.txt";

fs.exists(fileName, function(exists) {
  if (exists) {
    fs.stat(fileName, function(error, stats) {
      fs.open(fileName, "r", function(error, fd) {
        var buffer = new Buffer(stats.size);
        fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(error, bytesRead, buffer) {
          var data = buffer.toString("utf8", 0, buffer.length);
          console.log(data);
          fs.close(fd);
        });});});}});
```

I'd like to use it like a module:

```
//consumer.js
var fooreader = require('fooreader.js');
console.log(fooreader());
```

I understand that might be a little naive given the asynchronous read, so I tried putting 'fooreader' into a function that accepts a callback:

```
//fooreader.js
var fs = require("fs");
var fileName = "foo.txt";

var fooreader = function(callback){
fs.exists(fileName, function(exists) {
  if (exists) {
    fs.stat(fileName, function(error, stats) {
      fs.open(fileName, "r", function(error, fd) {
        var buffer = new Buffer(stats.size);
        fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(error, bytesRead, buffer) {
          var data = buffer.toString("utf8", 0, buffer.length);
          console.log(data);
          fs.close(fd);
          callback(data);
        });});});}});};
module.exports = fooreader;
```

and tried:

```
//consumer.js
var fooreader = require('fooreader.js');
fooreader(callback);
var callback = function(data){    
  console.log(data);
}
```

and got "TypeError: undefined is not a function".  How do I make the callback work?

Comment: so `callback` isn't being hoisted, because you are using variable assignment rather than function declaration syntax. If you said `function callback(data) { console.log(data) }` instaed, it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Define the callback before calling it in your last snippet. Everything else looks like it should work.

You have:

```
var fooreader = require('fooreader.js');
fooreader(callback);
var callback = function(data){    
  console.log(data);
}
```

When you run `fooreader(callback)`, it's before `callback` has been defined. Switch the order of the commands and everything should work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It works if I use an anonymous function to handle the callback.  Makes sense as it's passing the function back to the module ...

```
//consumer.js
var fooreader = require('fooreader.js');
fooreader(function (data){    
  console.log(data);
});
```